# Does Delphi have a pre-processor macro indicating the current file and line number?

Tags: delphi, macros, preprocessor

For example, C/C++ have the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros.

The purpose of this is for debugging.

**EDIT**: I am trying to use this to help diagnose problems as they occur. E.g.:

```
ShowMessage(Format('Error on line %i', [__LINE__])).`
```

Comment: No. The only built-in way I can think of is the [`Assert`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Assert) procedure.

Comment: Delphi has no preprocessor, and therefore no equivalent preprocessor macro. For debugging, use something like MadExcept, EurekaLog, or JclDebug (all of which you should be able to locate via Google), which use a detailed map file and a stack trace to determine that information when an exception occurs, or use Assert as @TLama suggests.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: While your edit shows you're listening to comments, it doesn't help. What "error" are you trying to diagnose? An exception? A certain condition existing (or not)? A calculation failure? It still appears that the options previously mentioned would work.

Comment: The function I am using executes SQL against a database connection. The first parameter is the SQL to execute, the second is "diagnostic" string, so that if the SQL throws an exception, it presents an error to the screen (e.g., `There is a problem with the SQL: ... Error: GB10`. The `GB10` is hard-coded in the calling function. I thought it might be easier to pass `IntToStr(__LINE__)` rather than a hard-coded string that could have duplicates (e.g., two different people call `processSql`, each in their own function, and for the diagnostic message they both write 'GB10').